# Cannot update LDAP admin password

Tags: ldap, python

I have the following python script to update LDAP password.

```
import ldap
from ldap import LDAPError
user_dn = "CN=******,OU=Admins,OU=Example Users,DC=Example,DC=com"
old_password = "pass01"
new_password = "pass02"

def change_password(user_dn, old_password, new_password):
    #ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
    ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT,0)
    #l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ds.example.com:3268")
    l = ldap.initialize("ldap://ds.example.com:389")
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS,ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_DEMAND,True)
    l.set_option(ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL,255)
    try:
        l.simple_bind_s("myacct@example.com", old_password)
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print "LDAP error1: {}".format(e)

    # Reset Password
    unicode_pass = unicode('\"' + str(new_password) + '\"', 'iso-8859-1')
    password_value = unicode_pass.encode('utf-16-le')
    add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password_value])]
    try:
        l.modify_s(user_dn,add_pass)
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print "LDAP error2: {}".format(e)
    l.unbind_s()

change_password(user_dn, old_password, new_password)
```

Which hits the second exception:

```
LDAP error2: {'info': 'Referral:\nldap://example.com/CN=*******,OU=Admins,OU=Example%20Users,DC=example,DC=com', 'desc': 'Referral'}
```

The user_dn entry is correct - exactly as it appears on the internal account management system. Am I getting this error because it's an admin password and needs to be handled differently? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Obvious question: are you running this in the context of a user that has the rights to make changes to the account?

Unless there's no security on your domain - this looks like an AD domain - you'll need to bind with a valid account, and that account will need to have the rights to modify the other one.

Second: for a Windows domain, you must do this over SSL, if you're not doing an auth first using NTLM or Kerberos. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/269190/how-to-change-a-windows-active-directory-and-lds-user-password-through-ldap

Finally, if you must use Python rather than .NET or Powershell, I highly recommend using the PyAD module, which uses ADSI-style methods that are a lot nicer than plain LDAP. https://zakird.com/pyad/index.html

Comment: There was an issue with the dn input, and, once I fixed it, I got to the next exception that said the user does not have sufficient privileges. Trying to get over that at the moment. Thanks for the help.